# C++ code listing exported to HTML using elyxer has problem with < and > symbols

Tags: lyx, html, export

C++ code listing exported to HTML using Elyxer has problem with < and > symbols for example `#include <iostream>` shown as `#include`.
I have to change manually all < to `&lt;` and > to `&gt;` that is very tedious and error prone. 
Is there any simpler way to get rid of this problem?

Comment: I think there is also `tex4ht` option for LyX to html conversion, you may try that